# Regex: Match malicious ASP session ID

Tags: regex, session, cookies, pcre

I'm trying to create a *MODSECURITY* rule (using PCRE) for whitelisting ASP session id key in the cookie header. Here is what came to my mind so far:

```
^(?!.*?ASP.NET_SessionId=[a-z0-9]+;.*?$).+
```

The website cookie header is like this:

```
Cookie: PortalAlias=Portal; Language_PostPortal=en-US; ASP.NET_SessionId=opn4y4n1qja0mtzm4sx4514k; portalroles=50FA411EBBAC79
```

So any cookie value with characters except `[a-z0-9]` in the ASP.NET_SessionId key must be blocked.Is there a best and more optimized regex(PCRE) to do this?

Comment: Are you using a PCRE wrapper in ASP.NET? This would be more better: `^(?!.*?ASP\.NET_SessionId=[a-z0-9]+;)`

Comment: @revo: `^(?!.*?ASP\.NET_SessionId=[a-z0-9]+;)` doesn't match but `^(?!.*?ASP\.NET_SessionId=[a-z0-9]+;).+` matches the payload and in less steps than mine.

Comment: Are you trying to match or to return something? If you want to return append `.+` to mine.

Comment: You tagged question with pcre but it's not clear if it is right or not.

Comment: As i said i'm trying to block cookies witch doesn't match my white-list characters. For example these payload: ASP.NET_SessionId=1d9rtFw5' and x=y--

Comment: @revo: It doesn't match. https://regex101.com/r/vowI2o/1

Comment: Sorry check this https://regex101.com/r/I5W4BG/1

Comment: Again I should say if this regex is going to be used in .NET the whole thing would be a mess. It's PCRE.

Comment: @revo: It's perfect. please answer so i accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of matching you can go through a replace method so that you are able to remove whole unwanted session id:

```
ASP\.NET_SessionId=[a-z0-9]*[^a-z0-9;][^;]*;\s*
```

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/sCTA3J/2)